# Fire event in hyperlink field gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a hyperlink field in my `gridview` as below:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText = "RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx"/>
```

Its basically a `runId`. Clicking this hyperlink will redirect to a page called `RunAnalysis`. I want to access the value of the `runId` which was clicked in this page.

I was thinking of using a query string but there is no event as far as I know that is fired on click of the hyperlink.

How to access the `runId` value in this page? Is there an event fired so to send a query string?

Comment: <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText = "RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx"/>

Comment: I m not sure about that but, you can try "CommandArgument" property to pass runID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly easy to do with query string. Make sure you pass the parameter:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx?runId={0}"
```

The value for the placeholder will be picked up from `DataNavigateUrlFields`, which you already have correctly setup.

In the code behind of the `RunAnalysis.aspx` page all you need to do is just to read the passed value from the `Request` object:

```
string runId = Request.QueryString["runId"];
```